# Symfony Upload doc, docx file using sfValidatorFile Mime type issue

Tags: file-upload, symfony-1.4, mime-types

I am using sfValidatorFile class to allow user to upload pdf or document in symfony 1.4.
But It's not working with document, It returns mime type octet-stream which prevent to upload the document.

I have tried with the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104127/uploaded-docx-files-turning-into-zip)!

But unfortunately it's not working. Here is my code.

```
'my_filename' => new sfValidatorFile(
              array ('required'=>false,
                     'mime_type_guessers' => array('guessFromFileinfo'),
                     'mime_types' =>  array ( 'application/pdf',
                                              'application/msword',
                                              'application/vnd.openxmlformats-
                                              officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',                
                                                  'application/vnd.ms-word',
                                                  'application/x-msword',
                                                  'application/msword;     charset=binary')) ,
                array( 'mime_types'=> 'only doc, docx and pdf files are allowed' )),
```

Also tried with msValidatorFile class solution provided on same link, but it allows to upload zip and rar too.

Is there any way to allow only pdf and documents to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not system dependent after putting some time I found another solution sharing here.

Using PHP mime_content_type function we can get exect mime type even after manually changed extension. Though it's little buggy not working on linux license version. But still on other platform we can use this.

Comment: You need to either add a bit more detail: It was fixed by upgrading to version X. Which System did you update? Operating System? Symphony? Help others who have the same or similar issues.

Comment: Please give more detail! I have same problem and need your solution! Thanks a ton!!!