# Symfony 1.4 cannot upload *.rar with sfWidgetInputFile and sfValidatorFile

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony-1.4, mime-types

I'm using sfValidatorFile and sfWidgetInputFile to support user upload file, which allow file types: doc, docx, zip and rar. It has no problem with them but Symfony throws error with files *.rar : `Invalid mime type (application/octet-stream).`

Here my validator config:

```
$this->validatorSchema['contract_file'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
      'required'   => true,
      'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/contracts',
      'mime_types' => array(
        'application/msword',
        'application/zip',
        'application/x-rar-compressed',
        'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
       ),
       'max_size' => $maxSize
    ));
```

I don't know why Symfony throws this errors while I have set `mime_types` for it? How to fix for upload *.rar?

### UPDATE

When clear `mime_types` config, Symfony allow upload file *.rar but it rename to *.bin. Why?

Comment: I found the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104127/uploaded-docx-files-turning-into-zip?rq=1 But now I'm at home and not allow using my company computer. Somebody help me confirm that! Thank's a lot!

Comment: According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977544/rar-zip-files-mime-type you should also use the mime type `application/octet-stream` when dealing with archive.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I have tried `application/octet-stream` but SF still rename file to *.bin

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look into the `sfValidatedFile` class there is a function there which sets the extension for `application/octet-stream` mime type to `.bin`. You can create your own class which extends the `sfValidatedFile` and overwrite the said file.

When configuring the `sfValidatorFile` you can pass the option `validated_file_class` with the name of your own class.

Something like this:

```
class myValidatedFile extends sfValidatedFile
{
    protected function getExtensionFromType($type, $default = '')
    {
        static $extensions = array(
            // ...
            'application/octet-stream' => '.rar',
            // ...  
        );

        return !$type ? $default : (isset($extensions[$type]) ? '.'.$extensions[$type] : $default);
    }
}
```

And in the form's `configure` function:

```
 $this->validatorSchema['contract_file'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
     // ...
     'validated_file_class' => 'myValidatedFile',
));
```

Comment: Oh, but what if user uploads *.exe? We can't check, `octet-stream` is generic for many file types.

Comment: I thought you only wanted the user to upload doc, docx, zip and rar files. You can fiddle with the `myValidatedFile` class to suit your need - e.g. for `application/octet-stream` files use the original extension.

Comment: yeah. I think the best is custom our validator. I will try at tomorow. Thanks a lot!